# Contar Items de um ListView

Tags: delphi

Preciso contar quantos itens tem adicionado em um `listview`, fiz o seguinte:

```
LV1.Items.BeginUpdate;
 try
   for i := 0 to LV1.Items.Count-1 do
     Label11.Caption := inttostr(i+1);
 finally
  LV1.Items.EndUpdate;
 end;
end;
```

Ele funciona mais tem um *bug*, quando adiciono 2 ITENS, aparece 2. Quando apago os 2 ITENS ao invés de aparecer 0, fica aparecendo "1". Alguma idéia?

Comment: Não entendi, vc já tem o método LV1.Items.Count ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contar os itens de um `Listview` através do uso de [`Listview.Items.count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(*como já mencionado no [comentário do Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13476/contar-items-de-um-listview#comment23491_13476)*).

```
ShowMessage('Quantidade de Itens ' + IntToStr(ListView1.Items.Count));
```

Enquanto ao problema relacionado ao código postado por você, o erro está em:

```
Label11.Caption := inttostr(i+1); // O erro: i+1
```

### Código corrigido

```
var
  I: integer;
begin
  LV1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to LV1.Items.Count do
      Label1.Caption := IntToStr(i);
  finally
    LV1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Porém o melhor método para fazer isso é utilizar o `Listview.Items.count`.

Comment: Então amigo eu testei dessa forma INTTOSTR(i);, mais tem um problema, só depois que aparece 2 ITENS no LISTVIEW que ele começa a contar do 1, entende ? Se aparecer somente 1 ITEM, continua em 0.

Comment: Resolvido amigos, segue o comando para quem precisar: Label11.Caption := IntToStr(LV1.Items.Count); conta perfeitamente....obrigado a todos pela ajuda!!!